# Google Maps Plugin for Android - How to use the standard Maps app, but receive info about trip?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

This app

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.headupnav.demo

and many of them like it, add a small overlay into the standard google maps app.  It then is able to get speed, direction and other information from google maps into its own custom app.  I need to do something similar.

I don't want to reinvent the wheel and make a mapping application, my app just needs the navigation, speed information provided to me to run in the background.

Looking through the list of APIs, https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/api-picker I do not see any the describe this plugin like model.

I am guessing the HUD is using the draw over other apps - but how does it get the real time data? (I can get speed from the GPS sensor - its the directions, turns etc that I am interested in)